# MVC 4 Web Api Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am looking for tips on how to set up routing in a Web API project. I have set up a controller called Resident with a method as follows:

```
public ResidentModel GetResidentInfo(int resId)
{
    //code to return ResidentModel object 

}
```

I have tried the following to map to this method in the route.config file.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Resident",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {  id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I am trying to access this method through a variety of ways:

```
http://localhost/resident/1 or 
http://localhost/resident/GetResidentInfo/1 etc...
```

I'm looking for some guidance on the process of setting up a controller then mapping to that controller method as when I try to access methods I've created it does not recognize them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Silly question: Is your controller called `Resident` or `ResidentController`? Can you try changing the redId parameter to id. and use that second URL?

Comment: What happens if you drop the "/1" in the request, and set "1" as the default parameter in the method?

Comment: Actually for a Web API project you probably need a URL like `http://localhost/api/resident/GetResidentInfo/1`

Comment: Also, how does your controller action return? What does that line look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your controller class should be called `ResidentController` (not just `Resident`) and inherit from `ApiController` (it really needs to implement `IHttpController`, but inheriting from that class is the easiest way).

Second, you should use `MapHttpRoute` instead of `MapRoute` for Web API controllers.

Next, the paramter `id` on the route doesn't match the parameter in your action. If you have a route such as the one below, you should be able to get to the second URL:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "WithAction",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{resId}");
```

And this would match the first one:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultAction",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{resId}",
    defaults: new { action = "GetResidentInfo" });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response the control is called ResidentController I figured you guys would take that as a given my apologies. Thank you Carlos this solved my issue I was able to get response at the following url after following your routing.            http://localhost/api/resident/GetResidentInformation/?resId=1